# QtNetwork - Unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, qt, symbols, unresolved-external

I'm currently writing app using tcp socket, but im not able to complie any code cuz i recive "unresolved external symbols". I add to my .pro file `QT       += core gui network` but it isnt helping.
I'm including headers like this `#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>`, when i change this line to this `#include <QtNetwork>`. I recive "no such file or directory", maybe there is a problem. 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Doesn't the `#include <QTcpSocket>` work too?

Comment: Have you _run qmake_ after you added the network module in .pro file?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.